# Downloaded image not being displayed iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, request, nsurl

I'm just starting to learn how to make network requests in iOS Swift. Below is a very simple image request where everything seems to be working. The task downloads the image with no errors but the imageView never displays the downloaded image. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let imageURL = NSURL(string: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseball#/media/File:Angels_Stadium.JPG")!

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(imageURL) { (data, response, error) in
            if error == nil {
                let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!)
                performUIUpdatesOnMain {
                    self.imageView.image = downloadedImage
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your function for switching to main, show that code, is the image setting line called?

Comment: Is this specific to the download?  What happens if you just set an image from your bundle in the body of `viewDidLoad`?  You should supply more details, or at least tell what things you've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is working fine except for the fact you're using a **wrong URL** and for that your `downloadedImage` is coming `nil` because it can't create an `UIImage` for this data, the correct URL is:

**https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/98/Angels_Stadium.JPG/1920px-Angels_Stadium.JPG**

Update your code code as the above code and everything should be work fine:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let imageURL = NSURL(string: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/98/Angels_Stadium.JPG/1920px-Angels_Stadium.JPG")!

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(imageURL) { (data, response, error) in

        guard error == nil, let data = data else { return }

        let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.imageView.image = downloadedImage
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Good bit of detective work! I didn't think to check the URL provided in the code but you are right. (Voted)

Comment: @DuncanC I checked because everything is well in code except from the fact of the URL, thanks :)

Comment: "I checked because everything is well in code..." What does that mean? If you want help debugging a problem, provide a complete description of what you've tried, and the results you are getting. If you had a print statement to make sure you were not getting an error, tell us that. Trying to play 20 questions to help you is a big waste of everybody's time.

Comment: @DuncanC I think you misunderstand my point in the comment, second I don't understand the rest of your comment regarding waste or time, etc

Comment: Thank you Victor for answering my question. I should have realized that the first URL wouldn't work since it loads an interactive view of the image instead of just the raw image file. If anyone else is as clueless as I am, to get the raw image file address you can just right click on the image and select "copy image address"

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting an error from NSURLSession your current code would fail silently. Don't do that.

Add a print statement inside your data task's completion block that logs the value of error and of data. Also log downloadedImage once you convert data to an image.

Finally, show us the code for your performUIUpdatesOnMain function.

Comment: He says the image downloads, so the `NSURLSession` should be fine.  But indeed very good point to ask for the `performUIUpdatesOnMain`.

Comment: He says "The task downloads the image with no errors" but if the code simply falls through without doing anything if there's an error, he can't tell if that's true or not.